# MySQL count problem

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table course:

```
CREATE TABLE course
    (COURSE_NO NUMERIC(8,0) NOT NULL
    ,DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(50) 
    ,COST NUMERIC(9,2) 
    ,PREREQUISITE NUMERIC(8,0)
    ,CREATED_BY VARCHAR(30) 
    ,CREATED_DATE DATE 
    ,MODIFIED_BY VARCHAR(30) 
    ,MODIFIED_DATE DATE 
    ,PRIMARY KEY (COURSE_NO)
    ,INDEX (PREREQUISITE)
    ) TYPE = INNODB;
```

I want to retrieve prerequisites and display the number of courses it is a prerequisite of

So far i understand i have to count the number of prerequisites a course has, but i dont understand how to display a count for each prerequisite.

Any help with this select statement would be appreciated.

Thanks, Mike

Comment: What is PREREQUISITE and how it is related to Course? It is not very clear how your data structured.

Comment: You have some courses. Does a single course have a single prerequisite which is in that course's field, prerequisite -- which represents the course_id of the prerequisite?

Comment: Yes wsorenson, that's how its structured. Your select statement works. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming my comment is correct, this should work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), prerequisite FROM course GROUP BY prerequisite;
```